# Disable button click after click and re-enable after 10 seconds in asp.net web form using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Currently, I am trying to achieve is disable a button after click and re-enable after 10 seconds. But it is not working.
HTML Code

```
<td>
      <asp:Button ID="btnResendOTP" runat="server" CssClass="button"
Text="Resend OTP" OnClientClick="disableButton()" OnClick="btnResendOTP_Click"/>
 </td>
```

JS Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableButton() {
        document.getElementById("<% btnResendOTP.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("<% btnResendOTP.ClientID %>").disabled = false; }, 10000);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: That did not solved my problem, I am getting this error!
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribute'

Comment: What error(s) are you getting with above code snippet ?

Comment: It is far better to do the `document.getElementById("<% btnResendOTP.ClientID %>")` once and assign it to a variable, which you then reuse. Performing that more than once, unless you expect the element with that ID to change between those times, is wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

I would do something along the lines of:

```
$("#mybtn").click(()=> {
   $("#mybtn").attr("disabled", true);
   $("#mybtn").delay(10000).attr("disabled", false);
});
```

If you need it as a named function then basically the same:

```
$("#mybtn").click(function btnclick() {
   $("#mybtn").attr("disabled", true);
   $("#mybtn").delay(10000).attr("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with the code?

Comment: @SagarTimalsina I updated it. Using `.attr` allows you to access the attribute of an element. In this instance, I am accessing it's disabled attribute and setting it to true. When I want to reactivate it, I delay it for 10 seconds then access the disabled attribute again and set it to false.

Comment: You're doing `$("#mybtn")` multiple times. This is one of the really bad habits which it's easy to fall into with jQuery, or other framework that trivializes expensive DOM walks. Unless it's possible the set of elements you're searching for changes between the different calls you're making, you should perform the DOM search *once* and assign it to a variable (that's what variables are for). Not doing so is unnecessarily wasteful, and makes your code harder to maintain (if the HTML design changes to needing a different ID, then you only need to change it in one location, if you use a variable).

Answer (score 1):

I just made a bit changes with getElementById. Please try with below code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableButton() {
        document.getElementById('<%= btnResendOTP.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('<%= btnResendOTP.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
        }, 10000);
    }
</script>
```

**.ASPX**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnResendOTP" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Resend OTP" OnClientClick="disableButton()" OnClick="btnResendOTP_Click" />
```

Comment: this code is also not working!

Comment: @SagarTimalsina Ok. Can you specify more about the issue if anything left in question. Also, post more information because above code should be work.

Comment: I have mentioned about my complete requirement.